# How tom find / get the DropBox Application Secret?

Tags: dropbox

Does anyone know where to find / obtain the DropBox application key? I only see the following under my app:

Status
Permission type
App key
Drop-ins domains

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be best addressed to the Technical Support of a third party.

Answer (score 0):

Drop-ins apps don't have secrets. If you're trying to use the Core API or Sync API, you'll need to choose the "Dropbox API" type when you first create your app.